# FlatList render too many times

Tags: react-native

I just got this issue when using FlatList in React native, I am using PureComponent, my data just has only 20 items but it renders like 30 times.

Here is my code:

```
export default class App extends React.PureComponent {
  state={
    data: [{key: '1'}, {key: '2'}, {key: '3'}, {key: '4'}, 
    {key: '5'}, {key: '6'}, {key: '7'}, {key: '8'}, 
    {key: '9'}, {key: '10'}, {key: '11'}, {key: '12'}, 
    {key: '13'}, {key: '14'}, {key: '15'}, {key: '16'}, 
    {key: '17'}, {key: '18'}, {key: '19'}, {key: '20'}]
  }
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList 
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            console.log(item.key)
            return (
              <MyItem>{item.key}</MyItem>
            );
          }}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default class MyItem extends React.PureComponent {
    render(){
      return(
        <View>
          <Text>{this.props.children}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
```

and this was what I got when running

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20

Comment: This is still present in react native v0.55.4, I guess it is a bug. If you have large lists it can significantly cause stuttter.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. There should not be any issues while running this code.

How are you know how many times your screen renders? Here since your state is static it should render only once, until and unless you are doing `setState` somewhere in your code.

Otherwise this piece of code is fine.

Comment: Hi Yash, i use console.log() in renderItem function to see how this function works, first it renders 10 items, then it render the first 10 items again.